# GNOME - disable minimum width & height restrictions for all windows

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I am using Gnome 3.22 and it is great. But there are some windows which have minimum width and minimum height defined and this is bad! How bad this is can be noticed when you start using any kind of Gnome extension for tiling windows.

I use [Sheltile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/) which is great except that it fails to set proper height and width on a small resolution monitor, because minimum width and height are set.

For example if I drag window in the top right corner of the screen at first it is shown that window will take 1/4 of the screen:

[image]

But it fails miserably after I let go of the left mouse button (window's top left corner has proper position):

[image]

Same thing happens if I drag the window to the bottom left corner. At first it looks like it will be resized okay:

[image]

But it again fails miserably stretching beyond the screen and panel in the bottom (window's top left corner has proper position).

[image]

Even when I try to shrink window by manually drag any of it's corners I can't do it. Is there a way to disable all window's minimum width & height restrictions in Gnome 3.22? As you can see it is causing a lot of trouble and proves that programmers shouldn't anticipate user's moves too much. It ends miserably... Symptom is the same with all Gnome's tiling extensions.